# Returning a variable value to a rake script

Tags: ruby, variables, powershell, rake

I'm executing a rake script that calls a powershell function. The function returns a value, how can i get this value and provide it to my rake template file?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If the PowerShell integration within Rake is the same as calling out to anything other console EXE then I expect that you would capture the stdout from the PowerShell invocation.